# Trouble updating metapackage

Tags: xubuntu

I'm having trouble downloading xfce4 metapackage. I don't have a desktop yet just cmd line and this is my first time on linux.

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

brings back Unable to locate package xfce4

Does that with all packages, leads me to
    sudo apt-get update
Leaves me with temporary failure resolving 'downloads-distro.mongodb.org'

Read some solutions to fix this but it had me going in circles with no avail. Need to get this working from cmd prompt.

So I'm having trouble updating and am lost here without a desktop client. If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please add a bit more information? Which system do you have installed? Is the network working correctly? It seems you can't resolve the repository address, which here works ok... downloads-distro.mongodb.org has address 23.20.48.204.

Answer (score 0):

To install XFCE desktop environment, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

If you want to install the complete Xfce desktop, with all the extras, then use the following command

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. However it returns. add-apt-repository: command not found

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked.  Did you add `sudo` to it?

Comment: Yea added sudo. Looked into it and it took me here. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2009826 - I think I need to reinstall.. Been going in circles with this for a few hours trying to install...

Comment: It shouldn't take anywhere.  Try copy and past the commands into terminal, and let me know.

Comment: Not what I meant, the link is to a guy experiencing the same problem as me who had to resort to reinstalling. I figure it must be a bad distro but I have no idea what to do now as I can't continue to download anything and on another note I just installed from a usb and it wont load a fresh install menu when I boot with it now! Sigh...

Answer (score 0):

A command line install will most likely lack the universe and multiverse repositories. 
Unfortunately, xfce is located there.
Edit the repository file with  `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Inside this file, you will see something like this:

```
deb http://some-server-address/ubuntu/ your-ubuntu-flavor main
```

edit this and everywhere you see `main` to:

```
deb http://some-server-address/ubuntu/ your-ubuntu-flavor main universe multiverse
```

After a `sudo apt-get update` should a `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` give you the whole shebang.